# JDBC - setAutoCommit for read only operation

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

Let's say I have a common method which creates a DB connection:

```
Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = ... // create the connection
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    return con;
}
```

I put the `setAutoCommit(false)` call here so that callers of this method never have to worry about setting it. However, is this a bad practice if the operation executed by the caller is only reading data? Is there any extra overhead?

My personal opinion is that it's better to centralize the logic in one place, that way callers never have to set the auto commit and this avoids code redundancy. I just wanted to make sure it didn't incur any unnecessary overhead for a read only operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I put the setAutoCommit(false) call here so that callers of this method never have to worry about setting it.

This is fine IMO and I personally believe that one should never ever enable auto-commit mode inside an application. So my recommendation would be to turn off auto-commit.

> However, is this a bad practice if the operation executed by the caller is only reading data? Is there any extra overhead?

From a strict performance point of view, it's starting and ending a database transaction for every SQL statement that has an overhead and may decrease the performance of your application.

By the way, SELECT statements are affected by [`setAutoCommit(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) according to the javadoc:

> Sets this connection's auto-commit
>   mode to the given state. **If a
>   connection is in auto-commit mode,
>   then all its SQL statements will be
>   executed and committed as individual
>   transactions**. Otherwise, its SQL
>   statements are grouped into
>   transactions that are terminated by a
>   call to either the method commit or
>   the method rollback. By default, new
>   connections are in auto-commit mode.
>
> **The commit occurs when the statement
>   completes.** The time when the statement
>   completes depends on the type of SQL
>   Statement:
>
> - For DML statements, such as Insert, Update or Delete, and DDL statements,
>     the statement is complete as soon as
>     it has finished executing.
> - **For Select statements, the statement is complete when the associated result
>     set is closed.**
> - For CallableStatement objects or for statements that return multiple
>     results, the statement is complete
>     when all of the associated result sets
>     have been closed, and all update
>     counts and output parameters have been
>     retrieved.

Comment: I disagree about the performance issue of beginning and ending transactions. This has never been my experience, but rather that several long transactions cause more bottlenecks than many small ones. Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Answer (score 5):

Autocommit doesn't have any value for `SELECT` queries. But turning autocommit off is indeed a more common practice. More than often you'd like to fire queries in a transaction. Most of the connection pools also by default turns it off. I would however suggest to make it a configuration setting of your connection manager and/or to overload the method taking a boolean argument, so that you at least have *any* control over it for the case that.

Comment: @BalusC A `select` query can introduce shared locks, or require extra copies of the read tuples for the duration of the transaction (depending upon the isolation level). Wouldn't you say that means autocommit *does* have value for `select` queries?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I wanted to give give a different opinion on the issue.

**Performance**

The performance overhead from transactions varies with the concurrency control mechanism: normally multi-version concurrency control or locking. The concern expressed in the other answers seems to be down to the cost of ending a transaction, but in my experience the biggest pain is long-running transactions, which can cause performance bottlenecks. For instance, if the DBMS uses locking, some parts of a table cannot be updated until a transaction involving that table has been terminated. More frustrating in systems such as Oracle is that DDL operations (`ALTER TABLE`, etc.) have to wait until all transactions using that table have ended, leading to troublesome time-outs. So don't think your transaction has no penalty if you're just using `SELECT`s.

**Conventions**

A subtle problem with setting the autocommit behaviour off is that you are changing from the default, so anyone else working with your code may not be expecting it. It is *really easy* to leave an accidental path through a function than does not end with an explicit `commit` or `rollback`, and this can lead to unpredictable behaviour in subsequently called functions. Conversely, a large proportion of the DB-interfacing code that I have seen contains a single statement within each function, for which autocommit behaviour is very well suited. In fact a lot of the multi-statement functions I have encountered could have been re-written as single statements with a little more SQL know-how - poor approximations to joins implemented in Java are sadly common.

My personal preference, based on reasonable experience, is as follows for any functions making calls to a database:

- keep to the default JDBC behaviour of auto-commit on;
- when your function includes more than one SQL statement, use an explicit transaction by setting `setAutocommit(false)` at the start of each function and calling `commit()` (or `rollback()` if appropriate) at the end, and ideally `rollback()` in the `catch` block;
- enforce the default by putting `setAutocommit(true)` in the `finally` block that wraps your JDBC calls in the function (unlike APIs such as PHP/PDO, JDBC won't do this for you after `commit()`/`rollback()`);
- if you're feeling extra defensive, explicitly set your choice of `setAutocommit(true)` or `setAutocommit(false)` at the start of every function;

Comment: "keep to the default JDBC behaviour of auto-commit on" - don't really agree with that approach. I always turn it off when writing java code, you can refer here for reasons why: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:433819661301  Even for a single statement transaction, it's just clearer to keep it turned off and let the client code have complete control over the transaction.

Comment: @dcp Depends how well you understand transactions. Many people don't, but still write code to work with databases (think of all the lamp stacks out there, and all the wrapper code like in Ruby that hide the transactional behavior). Auto commit avoid the pernicious bugs of statements appearing to work but not persisting between sessions.

Comment: I can't argue with you there, because lack of database understanding is definitely a problem.  I know when we interview people, they may know .Net/Java/Whatever language/etc. very well, but ask them to write a simple SQL statement or explain transaction isolation levels and they have no idea how to answer. I see it as a big problem, because relational databases are still key, and people need to understand how to use them. That's why I stand by turning auto-commit off, and expecting more from developers and forcing them not to rely on tools.

Comment: dcp - the ask tom link you provided doesn't seem to provide any reasons for turning auto commit off other than that the titular Tom calls it "silly". Is there any actual reason? Perhaps a different ask tom article where he notes some performance or functional issue with short-lived transactions?

Comment: @Tom Dibble - Here's another link from asktom: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:314816776423  If you scroll about halfway down, you'll see Tom's comments: "you should always finish your own work - you should explicitly commit or rollback based on YOUR logic. Never rely on the environment to do it, it might do something different ".  The bottom line is that transactions represent a unit of work that a client packages together, therefore, the client should define when that work is committed.

Answer (score 1):

I would never have autoCommit set to true anywhere in the application.
The performance overhead if at all any is nothing compared to the side
effects of a `autocommit=true` connection.

You say you would never use this connection for DML. But that is the *intention*, maintained perhaps by coding standards etc. But in practice, it *is* possible to use this connection for DML statements. This is enough reason for me to never set auto-commit on.

`Select` statements are definitely going to take some memory/CPU/network. Let the overhead of autocommit be  a (very marginal) fixed overhead on every select statement, to make sure data integrity and stability of your application is maintained.