# Call commit on autoCommit=false connection for SELECT statements JDBC?

Tags: sql, web-applications, jdbc, transactions, commit

I do have a webapp written in Java on Tomcat, all connections should be `autoCommit=false` by default. Now, if I do run SELECT statement only in a transaction. Do I still need to call `commit()` or is it sufficient just to close the connection?

For what it's worth: I am on Oracle 11.2.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3794269/696632) but does not actually give an answer for this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sufficient to close the connection, no need to call `commit` or `rollback`.

But according to [connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29), it is [recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) to call either commit or rollback.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Select statements do not disturb the underlying model or the data contained within the model. It is safe to close the connection without calling any commands related to transactions (like `commit`).</s>

Actually strike that. I had not considered adjacent selects made to a model in my first answer. Say you execute `select id from users where age > 20` and follow it up with `select id from users where age = 20`, any updates made between these queries would affect the ACID nature of the selects and return duplicate results within the 2 queries. To guarantee consistent results you would need to wrap both selects in the same transaction with a commit().

So yes, It makes sense to commit your selects.

Comment: Thanks, I would rather tend to make ALL DB calls uniform and perform always a rollback or commit explicitly.

Comment: I've updated my answer after thinking about the question a little more. Yes, please wrap your selects within a transaction. It makes sense.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Wouldn't it simply be necessary to be in `autoCommit=false` mode, you wuld retain ACID here?

Comment: Implicit transactions are not started until you perform a commit() in autoCommit=false mode. This is in contrast to the autoCommit=true mode where every statement sent to the database is automatically part of a transaction and is committed.