# Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still alive Exception on connection.close()

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, derby

I have a method that creates a Connection with Embedded Derby Database and performs a Select query on it.

```
public PersonMID findPersonMID(String personAlias, CodeUID aliasTypeCodeUID, LogicalDomainMID logicalDomainMID) throws SQLException
{
    Connection connection = getConnection();

    try
    {
        QueryExecutor<Long> findPersonIdByPersonAliasExecutor = FindPersonIdByPersonAliasDelegate.getExecutor(authority,connection, personAlias);

        Long result = findPersonIdByPersonAliasExecutor.execute();

        if(result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return PersonMID.create(authority, result);
    }
    finally
    {
        JDBCAssistant.close(connection);
    }
```

Here is what my query looks like:

```
select P.PRSON_ID from PRSON_ALIAS PA join PRSON P on P.PRSON_ID = PA.PRSON_ID and P.LOGICAL_DOMAIN_ID = ? where PA.PRSON_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = ? and    PA.ALIAS = ?
```

When I run through this code, I get an Exception 
`JDBCException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.`

But when I call `Connection.commit()` before I close the `Connection`or set `autoCommit` `true` (it is set to `false` by default for my `Connection`) for my `Connection`, it is allowing me to successfully close the connection and get the reqired result.

But do I really need to call `commit()` for a `Select` operation? What's there to commit? Is there a lock somewhere that is not being released if I dont commit?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656034/call-commit-on-autocommit-false-connection-for-select-statements-jdbc/) says I shouldn't have to do it. I should be able to close my connection without having to commit or rollback.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you force the auto commit mode with connection.setAutoCommit(true) ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto In that case I am able to close the connection without any errors.

Comment: So I suspect that somewhere in the global configuration of derby, this no more the auto commit mode that is enabled by default. What does getAutoCommit() returns after getting the connection? Or maybe there is something not wrong if the method getConnection()

Comment: do you use a connection pool? if so check its configuration to ensure that it doesn't disable auto commit by default

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I know for a fact that `autoCommit` for my connection is set to false and I believe that's how it should be. My question was why should I have to commit anything for a Select statement? There is no change in the Database model.

Comment: If you are not in auto commit mode according to the isolation level chosen, the records that match with your query could be lock until you commit the transaction to release the locks

Comment: So I _do_ need to commit the transaction even after a select statement? Does that mean the answer in the post I linked is incorrect? Or it just depends on the type of connection?

Comment: No you don't need to commit anything if you are really in auto commit mode, that's why I wanted to know the value of getAutoCommit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **not** in `autoCommit` mode, then a `SELECT` statement is in fact holding read locks, depending on your isolation level, and so committing a `SELECT` query is more than a no-op.

Yes, there is no change to the database, but the commit still tells the database engine that your transaction is finished looking at the data, and it can therefore allow other transactions to modify the data.

Here's some background material:

1. Isolation levels and concurrency; https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevconcepts15366.html
2. Shared locks: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevconcepts842304.html